# Can NSTemporaryDirectory be flushed while app is running?

Tags: ios, ios8, temp

When my iOS app loads, it copies a bunch of files to the `NSTemporaryDirectory` in case those are missing. However, my app assumes that `NSTemporaryDirectory` files are persisted while the app is running.

Can I safely assume that `NSTemporaryDirectory` files are persisted while the app is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can safely assume that. There's no statement that I can find to that effect in the docs, and here's what the docs do say about the Caches directory:

> On iOS 5.0 and later, the system may delete the Caches directory on rare occasions when the system is very low on disk space

That leads me to think that persistence of the temporary store is not guaranteed either. My advice would be: if you need assured persistence, use another location, just in case. Or be prepared to check, even while the app is running, that the file is still there and recreate it again if need be.